# Adding new user to multiple unix servers using terminal

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, expect

I am working within a company and require myself to be added onto different branch servers. The current way of doing this is:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/sd-adduser test "Test User"
```

This needs to be done individually logging into each server manually - which is about 20 servers. I vaguely know of expect which allows you to do add a user to multiple servers? Could anyone point me in the right direction? Or provide me the script to do this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Pseudo-shellscript; Perhaps something like `serverlist="1.1.1.1 1.1.1.2 1.1.1.3"` and then a `for server in $serverlist; do ssh $server sudo /usr/local/bin/sd-adduser test "Test User"`

Comment: Add the ssh `-t` option to help with password prompts.

Comment: Hi @Jite can you be more clear i'm not very familiar with unix systems, also where do I type this within one server terminal and it will work for all....or??

Comment: Hi @ThomasDickey please can you ellaborate I'm a noob when it comes to unix...sorry!

Comment: When you use `ssh` to run a command remotely, that command is normally not on a "real" terminal (tty), and commands such as `sudo` will refuse to prompt for a password.  The `-t` option tells `ssh` to (try to) make that command work interactively.

Comment: Use a proper centralised user database. If you are a Windows shop with some \*nix servers, just piggyback on your active directory, otherwise use LDAP.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [multi-ssh](https://github.com/denis-sokolov/multi-ssh) could help you or [pssh](http://www.theether.org/pssh/) or [pdsh](http://code.google.com/p/pdsh/).

In the long run you probably want a central user management like LDAP.

Comment: pssh is useful, but as I recall, has problems merging the results into a coherent list (particularly confusing when the remote machine prompts for input).

Comment: Hi flexus, I have putty, can I use this to do this? If so which server can I carry out this from? For example there is a head office server, If I log in through there, have the script file ready and carry out the command? Or have I got completely the wrong idea?

Comment: Yes, you can use putty to log into the head office server. There you install for example pdsh and run your commands on all servers from the head office server.

Answer (score 0):

Routine administration tasks such as this can be done using a script that reads a list of server names and runs a command.  Something like this "each-host" script:

```
#!/bin/sh
for server in $(cat mylist)
do
    ssh -t $server "$@"
done
```

where `mylist` is a file containing the list of servers.

Thus

```
each-host sudo /usr/local/bin/sd-adduser test "Test User"
```

would run the OP's command on each host.  Once you get that working, you could tidy up a little, making it less verbose (not printing `/etc/motd`);

```
#!/bin/sh
for server in $(cat mylist)
do
    echo "** $server"
    ssh -q -t $server "$@"
done
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for the answer, so basically the mylist would be a .txt file? If so how would the i.p addresses be listed such as, would there be a comma after one or would there be a quotation mark please can you show me for example: "192.111.1, 192.111.2, 192.111.3" Sorry to be a pain. Also the each host script would that be a part of the script or is that a command. Thanks

Comment: yes - `mylist` would be a text-file: the for-loop expects the addresses to be separated by blanks (or newlines).  I meant for the script shown to be named `each-host`.

Comment: Hi Thomas, I have tried the above and get an error: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: Perhaps you created the script on Windows (where editors frequently use carriage-return/line-feed endings).  Unix and Linux need scripts using line-feed endings alone.  The dos2unix utility (on Linux) can convert.

Comment: For example [this page](http://askubuntu.com/questions/304999/not-able-to-execute-a-sh-file-bin-bashm-bad-interpreter)